# How to change column width based on the number of columns present?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

Take the following reactstrap example:

```
       <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col md={4}>
            <TodoAdd />
          </Col>
          <Col md={8}>
            <TodoList />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

At times, the second column is not present in the DOM. When this occurs, I would like for the 'md' property on the first column to be {12}.

Another way to put it, I would like for columns to be fluid, i.e. take up the full width of the row when sibling columns aren't present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <TodoAdd />
      </Col>
      <Col md={8}>
        <TodoList />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

The first column will take up whatever amount of space is left by the others columns who do have their size mentioned (via md, sm etc.)